# How to pass a path from "open with" to an executable created by install4j?

Tags: command-line, install4j

I'm trying to enable an executable (created by install4j) to work with a path given by an "open with" user interaction on a file.

On macOS (same should be true for other platforms AFAIK), when one right-clicks a file and chooses "open with -> Application", the application will be fired up and the path to the file will be given as an argument.

I read a lot of install4j tutorials, found a lot of command-line-related stuff, but didn't find how to get this running.

Currently, when I open a file with the created App, the path will be ignored.
When I start my Java application via command line, it works fine.

Any ideas what to set up in install4j to make this work?

Thanks a lot.

Edit:
After Ingo's suggestion I added this to my launcher class, but somehow it doesn't get called:

```
        public void start(Stage aPrimaryStage) {

            StartupNotification.registerStartupListener(aPath -> {

                logger.log("StartupListenerCalled: " + LocalDateTime.now());

                try {

                    setFilesListToStageProperties(externalPathStringToFilesList(aPath), aPrimaryStage.getProperties());
                }
                catch (IOException e) {

                    showError(Thread.currentThread(), e);
                }
            });

            logger.log("Application start: " + LocalDateTime.now());

            super.start(aPrimaryStage);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On macOS (same should be true for other platforms AFAIK), when one right-
> clicks a file and chooses "open with -> Application", the application will be
> fired up and the path to the file will be given as an argument.

This is not the case for application bundles on macOS. You have to use the [startup notification API](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/launcher/StartupNotification.html). This also works for single instance mode on Windows and Linux, where only the first invocation will pass the file path as an argument to the main method.

The startup listener API uses `java.awt.Desktop.setOpenFileHandler` under the hood which only works if you register a file association. From the documentation on that method:

> Please note that for Mac OS, notifications are only sent if the Java app is a bundled application, with a CFBundleDocumentTypes array present in its Info.plist.

For a method to add a file association for all file types, see this blog post:

https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/01/open-in-all-files/

In the launcher wizard, under Executable info-> macOS options, you can add an arbitrary fragment to the Info.plist file.

Comment: Hi Ingo
Thank you very much for your answer and the suggestion.
Finally I came to try it out.
Anyhow the StartupListener does not seem to get called in macOS (Big Sur) in case of "open with" on a file.
I added a call to my logger within the Listener's callback method and I do not see anything with regards to this within my logfile (every other logging entry can be found as expected, so the logger should be fine).
Any more ideas?
Thanks again!

Comment: install4j itself uses this API for .install4j project files, does that work on your machine? It works for me on macOS 11. Are you sure the correct application bundle is invoked?

Comment: Thanks again for coming back to this.
I can be sure, since in my app I have a help menu item which opens a window with the current system properties:
`
install4j.appDir=/Applications/Document Archiver/DocumentArchiver.app/../
install4j.exeDir=/Applications/Document Archiver/
install4j.launcherId=41
`
Also, in my "About" dialog I can see the version and build time, which are matching the build including the Listener.
You say you are using macOS 11. But is it also Big Sur (11.4)? From another bug I know they changed quite some things in Big Sur.

Comment: Opening a .install4j project file with the install4j executable works.

Comment: The changed the versioning recently and Big Sur is 11.x. 11.4 is just a bugfix release.  Maybe you can add the code that you are using to the question. Also, do you have a "Create a file association" action in your installer for that file type? What install4j version do you use?

Comment: You are totally right - after 20 years they changed how they increment the macOS version numbers. I added the code which registers the StartupListener to my original post. As I said, the application start log entry can be found in the log, the one within the callback not.
Version of install4j is 9.0.2. I didn't create a file association, since my app can open all kind of files, so I would have to create file associations for all kind of file types (I guess it is not possible to use "*" as "File extension" (The help text for this action only speaks of multiple extensions)?). Thanks as always.

Comment: I'm afraid it will not work without file associations. I've edited my answer to address this point.

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestion. I now added a file association to TXT files (to try it out). I can see that the association is created; when I right-click a TXT file and select "open with", my app is being presented as an option. Anyhow the callback is still not called. Giving you a chance to try it out, the current installer can be obtained here: https://www.sophisticatedapps.com/downloads/DocumentArchiver_macos_2_3_0-SNAPSHOT.dmg - Sourcecode at https://github.com/Document-Archiver/com.sophisticatedapps.archiving.document-archiver - Logs in ~/Library/Logs/DocumentArchiver/event.log TNX

Comment: It works for me: `[ingo@dev DocumentArchiver]$ tail -f event.log
Application start: 2021-06-13T10:01:50.276372
StartupListenerCalled: 2021-06-13T10:02:55.372405`

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort to try it out. I now used the same installer to install the app on my old MacBook (running on Catalina) and there I also don't see the Listener called. What I see from your log entries is that the Listener was called one minute after the application start. Since I don't believe your Mac is that slow, I assume you had a breakpoint / debugging session going on!? Maybe this alone could have changed the behavior!? I have seen code behaving differently in debug. If so, does it work for you without debugging?

Comment: I now found that the Listener is called when the application is running already. Anyhow one cannot assume that the app is running. For sure one expects the app to open the file also with a fresh start of the app.

Comment: You should call StartupNotification on the EDT like this: `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> StartupNotification.registerStartupListener(...))`

Comment: Thanks again for the further suggestion. Tried that out and also - since it is not an AWT, but a JavaFX Application - "Platform.runLater". Anyhow that doesn't change the situation ("open with" when app is running -> Listener is called / "open with" when app is not running yet -> Listener is not called). Also not quite sure what registering the Listener on the GUI thread should help with the situation. Doing the stuff within the Listener on the GUI thread is another topic.

Comment: Can you try to move the StartupNotification registration directly to the main method?

Comment: Yup - that did the trick! At least the Listener is called now. Currently doesn't help me, since in main I don't have access to the Stage (which I need to reference in the callback and which is created later), but the question is answered. Guess I have some thinking to do how to work with this situation. Thank you very much Ingo for all the good suggestions!

Comment: Thank you, I will add a note to the documentation that the registration should be done in the main thread.